# Print expression as is without evaluating it

Tags: c#, string, printing, expression

i want to print the expression Xmin and Ymin as is without calculating the final value .
i,e with the values of I and J as 1,2,3,4,5

example
when I=1

```
Xmin= Xmin ((1 - 1)*10 + (1 - 1)*1)
```

is there a way to do it .. I tried the following code, but no luck:

```
int a, g;
a = 10;
g = 1;
for (int J=1; J<=5; J++)
{
    for (int I = 1; I <= 5; I++)
    {
        string Xmin = Convert.ToString((I - 1)*a + (I - 1)*g);
        string Ymin = Convert.ToString((J - 1) * a);
        Debug.WriteLine("X=" + Xmin + "Y=" + Ymin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use String.Format:

```
string Xmin = String.Format("({0} - 1)*{1} + ({0} - 1)*{2}", I, a, g);
```

Also, in .NET 3.5 you can use expression trees, but I daresay that would be a much more complicated solution than just using String.Format.

Comment: I'm tempted to throw in an `Expression` version, just for chuckles... but it would probably be a hundred lines (or so), compared to your one-liner ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the expression in a string in order to do that, perhaps using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
string Xmin = String.Format("Xmin=({0} - 1)*{1} + ({0} - 1)*{2}", I, a, g);
string Ymin = String.Format("Ymin=({0} - 1) * {1}", J, a);

Debug.WriteLine("X=" + Xmin + "Y=" + Ymin);
```